# Sandbox: Testing in app purchase issue (no products retrieved from app store connect)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, storekit

All of a sudden, I am no longer able to test in app purchases on `testflight` builds.

`try await Product.products(for: [productID])` returns an empty array.

Production (app in AppStore) functions just fine. But when I test the release build of the production version or any other versions, the fetch returns an empty array. This seems to be a sandbox issue.

The ID is correct, Tax and banking forms are valid... This isnt the first release with in-app purchase or subscriptions so I am not sure why I am having this sandbox issue.

Comment: These things are really frustrating, had it as well. Usually it fixes itself within 24 hours. Have you tried with another sandbox-user?

Comment: Ya you're right, it fixed itself two days later with no changes on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved itself two days later with no changes on my end.